# Exclude default CSS from rmarkdown::render

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm rendering an R Markdown document to HTML with `rmarkdown::render`. The generated HTML includes a lot of CSS I don't want. I'd like to exclude all of that, and also add a reference to my own stylesheet. How can I do this, preferrably in the calling code, rather than by editing the R Markdown document?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the theme to null, and provide your own stylesheet in the header. See the [documentation in section 3.1.4.1](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#appearance-and-style)

Comment: This seems to work (I thought it didn't, but it turns out that the user stylesheet is inlined into the output document instead of linked to). Can it be done in calling code, though?